# Check spelling using MS Word ignore case sensivity

Tags: c#, ms-word, spell-checking

I check the spelling of words using Microsoft Word. I know that I can check the spelling using this:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
bool correct = app.CheckSpelling(word);
app.Quit();
```

This works fine, but I want to ignore if the word is written in upper case or in lower case. I'm checking german words and they can begin with a upper-case letter, but if I check a text, where every word is written in lower case this method will return `false` for words that usually begin with a upper case letter.

So how can I ignore the case sensivity? I tryed change the parameter `ignoreUppercase` of the method, but it still returns `false`:

```
bool correct = app.CheckSpelling(word, null, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IgnoreUppercase` applies to ALL CAPS, not to title case.

As title case capitalization of proper nouns is an integral part of the German language (no matter what some people choose to do), the proofing tools honour it. This is not an "option" that can be turned on/off.

You can build a conversion to make the word is title case and test the word again. For example:

```
if (!correct)
{
  CultureInfo cultureInfo   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
  //Create TextInfo object.
  TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

  //Convert to title case.
  Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToTitleCase(word));
  bool correct = app.CheckSpelling(word, null, true);
}
```